# How to encircle section of matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: matrices, arrays, draw

I am currently working on a lab report where I have to explain the Gaussian Elimination Method for a matrix. As part of my explanation, I want to circle/oval portions of a matrix.

Is there any way to circle the main diagonal of a matrix or a corner of it? Pics below with examples. I am thinking I may have to use a `\put` structure on top of an array/matrix environment but I do not know how to do that.

EDIT: Here's what I currently have to generate the matrix that I drew on in the pictures:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

...

\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             1 & -1 &  3 & -3 \\
            -1 &  0 & -2 &  1 \\
             2 &  2 &  4 &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
```

[image: Circle the main diagonal]

[image: Circle the bottom left corner]

[image: Circle the top right corner]

Comment: HI ! Could you show us what you code so far ? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Added the code I used for the matrix, plus the obnoxiously long list of packages I'm using. Let me know if you need more, I don't think I have much more that may be relevant to the question though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible way using `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             \tikzmarknode{A11}{1} & -1 &  3 & -3 \\
            -1 &  0 & -2 &  1 \\
             2 &  2 &  \tikzmarknode{A33}{4} &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw let \p1=($(A33)-(A11)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
 node[rotate fit=\n1,fit=(A11) (A33),draw,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             1 & -1 &  3 & -3 \\
            \tikzmarknode{B21}{-1} &  0 & -2 &  1 \\
             \tikzmarknode{B31}{2} &  \tikzmarknode{B32}{2} &  4 &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(B21) (B31) (B32),inner sep=2pt] (FB){};
\path (FB.south east) arc(-90:45:4pt) coordinate(aux1);
\draw (aux1) arc(45:-90:4pt) -- ([xshift=4pt]FB.south west)
arc(-90:-180:4pt) -- (FB.north west) arc(180:45:4pt) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             1 & \tikzmarknode{C12}{-1} &  \tikzmarknode{C13}{3} & -3 \\
             -1 &  0 & \tikzmarknode{C23}{-2} &  1 \\
             2 &  2 &  4 &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fit=(C12) (C23) (C13),inner sep=2pt] (FC){};
\path (FC.north west) arc(90:225:4pt) coordinate(aux2);
\draw (aux2) arc(225:90:4pt) -- ([xshift=-4pt]FC.north east)
arc(90:0:4pt) -- (FC.south east) arc(0:-135:4pt) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A shorter solution is given by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             \tikzmarknode{A11}{1} & -1 &  3 & -3 \\
            -1 &  0 & -2 &  1 \\
             2 &  2 &  \tikzmarknode{A33}{4} &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[red] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(A11.north)
 (A33.north east) (A33.south)  (A11.south west)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             1 & -1 &  3 & -3 \\
            \tikzmarknode{B21}{-1} &  0 & -2 &  1 \\
             \tikzmarknode{B31}{2} &  \tikzmarknode{B32}{2} &  4 &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(B21.north west) (B21.north east)
 (B32.north east) (B32.south east) (B31.south west)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
    \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
        \begin{block}{ [ ccc| c ]}
            \bigstrut[t]
             1 & \tikzmarknode{C12}{-1} &  \tikzmarknode{C13}{3} & -3 \\
             -1 &  0 & \tikzmarknode{C23}{-2} &  1 \\
             2 &  2 &  4 &  0 \bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(C12.north west) (C13.north east)
 (C23.south east) (C23.south west) (C12.south west)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one replaces all `\tikzmarknode` by `\tikzmarknode[inner sep=1pt]`, this becomes

[image]

Comment: That looks really good!

thats a lot of code though...

Comment: @elkshadow5 Yes. I slightly simplified it. One could write Ti*k*Z styles that do the computations, if that's not already been done somewhere.

Comment: How would I go about making the lines thicker/wider?

Comment: @elkshadow5 You need to replace `\draw[red]` by `\draw[red,very thick]` or something like this.

Comment: I figured it out. I had an extra coordinate marked that messed it up